# Calling "fork() execvp() _exit()" , and the process is not exiting

Tags: c, fork, execvp

So the brief summary is- I have a program which recursively searches for a file with a certain extension. Each time it finds one, it makes a copy, makes some changes to the copy, creates a patch (by using diff and execvp()) and delete the original file.

The problem I'm having is, after several hundred files, fork() returns with "Resource temporarily unavailable". I added a counter to see how many processes are still running when this failure happens, and it looks like none have been closed- the number of processes open is always the same as the number of files processed.

Now, I was under the impression that the flow should go something like this-
fork();//creates a child process
dostuff();//in the child process
_exit(1);//return control to the parent

but things appear not to be so simple. Perhaps somebody here may spot something obvious I'm missing in the code.

I have posted the 'cleanup' function which is responsible for the forking & patching- the rest is split over several files so hopefully this is enough.

(argument "name" is the original filename, and "newname" is the modified copy.)

```
void cleanup (char * name, char * newname)
{
    if (pf)
    {
            pid_t patch_pid;

            char * const diffargs[5] = {thisdiff, "-u", newname, name, NULL};

            char * patchname = malloc(strlen(name) + 6);
            strcpy(patchname, name);
            strcat(patchname, ".patch");

            if((patch_pid = fork()) < 0 )
            {
                    printf("fork failed.\n%s\nfilecount: %ld\nopen forks: %d\n", strerror(errno), filecount, pcount);
                    exit(-1);
            }

            pcount++;

            if (patch_pid == 0)
            {
                    FILE *pfp;
                    if ((pfp = fopen(patchname, "w")) == NULL)
                    {
                            printf("Error opening file \"%s\" for writing.\n%s\n", patchname, strerror(errno));
                            exit(-1);
                    }

                    dup2(fileno(pfp), STDOUT_FILENO);
                    fclose(pfp);
                    execvp(diffargs[0], diffargs);
                    free(patchname);

                    if (remove(name) != 0)
                    {
                            printf("Error removing file %s\n%s\n", name, strerror(errno));
                            exit(-1);
                    }

                    if (rename(newname, name) != 0)
                    {
                            printf("Error renaming file %s\n%s\n", newname, strerror(errno));
                            exit(-1);
                    }
                    pcount--;
                    _exit(1);
            }
    }

    else if (!df && !xf)
    {
            if (remove(name) != 0)
            {
                    printf("Error removing file %s\n%s\n", name, strerror(errno));
                    exit(-1);
            }
            if (rename(newname, name) != 0)
            {
                    printf("Error renaming file %s\n%s\n", newname, strerror(errno));
                    exit(-1);
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: You do know that if the [`exec`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html) family of functions are successful they will not return? That means any code you have after your `execvp` call will not run unless the call fails.

Comment: Do you reap the exit status of the exited processes somewhere with `wait()`? If not, you create heaps of zombies filling up the process table.

Comment: They don't return any value unless there's an error.... but surely they eventually finish and execution continues?

Comment: Jens: no, I do not. I must confess I don't know where an appropriate place to wait() would be. I guess at the very end of the cleanup() routine?

Comment: What the `exec` family of function does is to *replace* the current process with the one from the loaded program. When you call it your current code will simply cease to exist for the process.

Comment: After `exec`, the child process is running a completely different program. When it finishes, the child process exits, it doesn't return to your code.

Comment: Joachim: right, so hence the fork()- this would ensure the once execvp is finished then the parent will continue on. correct? or no?

Comment: You should call `wait` in the `else` block of `if (patch_pid == 0)`.

Comment: Yes, the *parent* process continues to work as usual, because it's the child process that is changed. The problem here is that you have code in the child process after the `execvp` call, and that code will never run.

Comment: As for when to call e.g. [`wait` or `waitpid`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wait.html) (or its sibling functions) you could use the `SIGCHLD` [signal](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/signal.h.html) to learn when a child process has exited.

Comment: @ErikNyquist If you want to send a comment to a specific user, put `@` before their name. Otherwise they won't be notified that you sent them a message.

Comment: As for the cleaning up, you can do that in the parent process once a child process has exited. You can use `waitpid` to wait for any process, and it returns the pid of the process. Store the information (file names, memory allocated, etc.) in a table together with the pid and running status. Once the process exits the signal handler sets the table-entry for that process as not running, and the parent process in its main loop (or similar) cleans up the resources of the child process.

Comment: Consider just using the `system` library function to run a shell command (you can use `>` redirection there).

Comment: @Per Johansson- this is mostly a learning excercise (nobody wants a program that deletes comments from source files then creates a patch) so I'm gonna go for the more complex option. But thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two suggestions:

1. Understand that exec*() *replaces* your process (if successful). Any code following it is unreachable.
2. Reap the exit status of exited processes with one of the wait*() functions; possibly in a signal handler for SIGCHLD.
3. Bonus suggestion: Read W. Richard Stevens' *Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment*; it's the Bible for tasks like these.

Comment: *Any code following it is unreachable* -- Unless exec* fails ;)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want an `else` clause after the `fork` to handle the parent process as well.  Something like the following might work;

```
void cleanup (char * name, char * newname)
{
    if (pf)
    {
        /* SNIP - unchanged */

        if (patch_pid == 0) /* child */
        {
            FILE *pfp;
            if ((pfp = fopen(patchname, "w")) == NULL)
            {
                printf("Error opening file \"%s\" for writing.\n%s\n",
                       patchname, strerror(errno));
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            dup2(fileno(pfp), STDOUT_FILENO);
            fclose(pfp);
            execvp(diffargs[0], diffargs);
            perror("execvp");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        else /* parent */
        {
            pid_t rc;
            int stat;

            free(patchname);

            rc = waitpid(patch_pid, &stat, 0);
            if (rc < 0)
            {
                perror("waitpid");
                /* do something appropriate here */
            }
            else
            {
                /* if you care about your children */
                if (WIFEXITED(stat))
                {
                    printf("%d exited with status %d\n",
                           (int)rc, WEXITSTATUS(stat));
                }
                else if (WIFSIGNALED(stat))
                {
                    printf("%d terminated because of signal %d\n",
                           (int)rc, WTERMSIG(stat));
                }
                else if (WIFSTOPPED(stat))
                {
                    printf("%d was STOPPED with signal %d\n",
                           (int)rc, WSTOPSIG(stat));
                }
            }
            pcount--;

            if (remove(name) != 0)
            {
                printf("Error removing file %s\n%s\n", name, strerror(errno));
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            if (rename(newname, name) != 0)
            {
                printf("Error renaming file %s\n%s\n", newname, strerror(errno));
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also high recommend reading *Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment* by the late W. Richard Stevens.  Actually, you should add *UNIX Network Programming volume 1 & 2* to your list as well ;)

The other thing that I noticed is that you have a memory management error related to `patchname`.  The `malloc` call isn't accounting for the extra `NUL` character at the end of the string.

Comment: Thanks for the reading suggestions, @Jens & D.Shawley.
For anyone else looking at this, I also found this page to be really helpful (and I probably should have read it before posting on here...)
http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/glibc-manual-0.02/library_23.html